# How to set textview's full width?

Tags: android, xml

I have a listview's item model in a separate XML file which contains two textviews... I wanted to have full width for each textview so they would appear one at bottom of the other one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/area_bck"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/area_frg"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Text2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but it looks like it doesn't really set full width even using layout_gravity , setting percentage on width... any direction would be appreciated!

Thanks to all!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your LinearLayout orientation to "vertical"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/area_bck"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="Text1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/area_frg"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="Text2" />

</LinearLayout>
```